# Azure: permissions to list service principals

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need service principal to run `Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString "sa-*"` in order to find ApplicationIDs during deployment process

Which permissions to I have to assign to this service principal?

In the perfect scenario those should allow read only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the powershell command actually uses graph in the background, you would have to give it directory.read.all api permissions.

But if that doesn't work, then you'll have to assign the service principal to a role in the tenant that has access to read the sp info like. Directory Readers Role should be able to. Please note it could take a while to take effect, up to 24 hrs.