# How to grant a service principal permissions to run Get-AzADServicePrincipal?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I want to get information about a service principal in an Azure PowerShell task in my DevOps pipeline using `Get-AzADServicePrincipal` but I get this error.

`[Authorization_RequestDenied] : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`

The DevOps service principal has `Contributor` rights in the subscription.
I have created a custom role but unsure as to what permissions to assign to it so that I can run the command in my pipelines. My user account is `Subscription Owner`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you do not have permission to read service principals, maybe `Directory.Read.All` or `Application.Read.All` are not being enabled. Please provide the service connection to those permissions by granting admin consent.

To enable that, go through the following steps:

Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your DevOps resource -> API Permissions

[image]

[image]

- Now, click on `Grant Admin Consent` and it will change the status to
  granted (Green) .

[image]

After performing all these, redeploy the DevOps Pipeline and run `Get-AzADServicePrincipal` to get the information about service principal.

If still it does not work, assign `Directory Readers` and `Application Administrator` roles to service principal of DevOps pipeline.

[image]

**References:**

1. [Service Principal considerations when using Azure DevOps to manage
   RBAC on Azure Resource Groups | by Andrew Kelleher | Azure
   Architects | Medium](https://medium.com/azure-architects/service-principal-considerations-when-using-azure-devops-to-manage-rbac-on-azure-resource-groups-f9c35f39ded5#:%7E:text=The%20Service%20Principal%20%28SPN%29%20used%20by%20Azure%20DevOps,your%20Azure%20subscription%20is%20assigned%20the%20Contributor%20role.)
2. [Azure: permissions to list service principals - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797775/azure-permissions-to-list-service-principals)